# Migrate MvvmCross 5.0 to 6.0

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a project with Xamarin.Android and it was using MvvmCross 5.0 and we decides migrate to MvvmCross 6.0. This implicate to pass the project to netstandard 2.0. This has get some problems because some libraries don't compatiblies with netstandard 2.0. My questions are: should I pass my project Droid to netstandard? Why can I integrate plugins how Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat? Because when I try it I get this error:

> NU1202: Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.1 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.1 supports:
>     - monoandroid60 (MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0)
>     - monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
>     - monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1)
>     - monoandroid80 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0)
>     - monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)
>     - monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0)
>   Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
>   Incompatible packages: 1
>   Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'netStandard'.

Thanks for yours help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your core project should target .net standard and your .droid project should target a MonoAndroid version. For example v8.1.